# Algorithm for how many students in a class did better than a student given this information

Tags: c++, algorithm, statistics

I want to make a simple application that will take in:

1. number of students
2. class average (score/100)
3. median grade (score/100)
4. class standard deviation
5. the current grade of a student (score/100)

The output would be how many students did better than that student.

I'm interested in the best estimate possible with this information.

I'm just not sure how to go about calculating this.

The grades in my data set have the same average as the median, so please, simply explain how to do it this way.

Comment: If you want the answer to be accurate you have to provide details on all students.

Comment: Do u assume a normal distribution? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: Given that you want "the best estimate possible" this sounds like a statistics question, NOT a programming question.

Comment: Thats not a small assumption on a sample anywhere from 5-200.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How do you define "best"?  How are you going to test this algorithm?

Comment: Since grades are defined on [0,100] you **cannot** assume a normal distribution.

Comment: Also "best estimate" will depend on a number of hypotheses. Assuming you want to go with a Bayesian approach, and a Beta distribution model, and conjugate priors on the parameters of the Beta distribution, you'll have to choose arbitrarily some parameters for the prior distribution. (Google the terms above if you don't know Bayesian statistics, it is the way to go here).

Comment: Also if median != average your distribution is surely not normal.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: No you don't. This is a standard distribution. If you know the mean and standard deviation you can calculate the number of students above or below a certain grade level.

Comment: @Martin Of course, and I can calculate the radiation risks for the unfortunates in Japan </sarcasm>

Comment: @Alexandre C: Why not. The numbers have just been normalized this does not mean their distribution has changed. Score = ActualScore/MaxPossableScore * 100

Comment: @ Captain Giraffe: Given the population size affected you would get a relatively accurate count. Statistics works ask any insurance company. The illogical one is the wisdom of crowds: Given a large population asked to guess the result: the average of the crowd is usually better than any individual. Example: At a conference I was at they asked everybody to guess the number of lines of code in Windows Vista (only a small percentage where from MS though most were Dev/PM style people) the average of the crowd was off by less than 1%. Given that nobody new the answer that is **Strange**.

Comment: @Martin SciAm had an article about that good samples give good numbers, completely fascinating. 5000 ppl Guessing @ a bean jar of about 5000 beans, the mean was very impressive.  Still this is a question about the exact, provable number IMO.

Comment: @Martin: Since you normalize by something **which depends on the data**, then yes the distribution **has** changed. Normal distribution can reach arbirarily low and high numbers, yours is clamped between 0 and 100. If X_1...X_n are normal iid variables, then X_i / (max_k X_k) are no longer normal, since they are bounded. They follow a hard-to-compute distribution (I don't know the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenters above are correct that without more information you can't nail this down precisely. However, as Steve Jobs likes to say, real artists ship so here is what I would do if you need a ball park estimate.

The two most straight forward ways to go about this is to either assume the data is normally distributed or from a beta distribution (because the scores are bounded between 0-100). Because you said the mean and median are close in your data I will give code to calculate the quantity assuming a normal distribution.

A normal distribution has two parameters and a mean and a variance. The best estimate of the mean you are going to get is the sample mean from the data, and best estimate of the variance will be the square of the standard deviation. So you if you want to know how many students did worse than a particular score what you need is the cumulative distribution function.

```
double mu=sample_mean;
double sigma=sample_std_deviation;
int numStudents=sample_size;
int NumberBetterThan(double score,double mu,double sigma,int numStudents)
{
   double temp=(score-mu)/sqrt(2*pow(sigma,2.0));
   temp=0.5*(1+erf(temp));
   int result=numStudents*(1.0-temp); // truncates to int but you can return a float if you are ok with a fractional number of students
   return(result);

}
```

erf is the error function from statistics. You can find c++ code to implement it many places on the web. One such place is [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/archives/cplusplus/3634.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to know more than average, median, and standard deviation to have a probability distribution of the scores, and you need that distribution to figure out how many students did better.

If you assume a probability distribution (or know the distribution because the teacher graded on that curve), the number of students that did better would be `(cdf(maximum possible score) - cdf(student's score)) * number of students`, where cdf is the cumulative disribution function for that distribution.

Comment: Why do you need more than average and std? @Milo: Check out the cumulative distribution function at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: @Stefan I wrote that before before I knew he was assuming a normal distribution.

Comment: Given an a large enough sample size the distribution is a "Standard distribution" (ie a bell curve).

Comment: @Martin I think what you meant to say is that given a large enough sample size the distribution of the **mean test score** is normally distributed. That is what we get from the central limit theorem anyway. We can't say anything about the overall distribution of scores just from the sample size.